# How do I sort date column with this format?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Most dates in my table are formatted in **mm/dd/yyyy**. However, I have two dates that are in **mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy** format. What is the best way to sort it? The column should only sort on the first date (from date).

Thanks in advance.

Please see my test case here -

https://live.datatables.net/zasupaza/1/edit

```js
  
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MM/DD/YYYY');

$('#example_full1').DataTable({
     responsive: true,
fixedHeader: true,
order:[[  0, 'desc' ]] 

} );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />

  </head>
  <body>


<table id="example_full1" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th >2</th>
<th  >3</th>
<th>4</th>
</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>12/16/2007</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>


  
  <tr>
    <td>09/08/2014 - 09/12/2014</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>08/16/2020</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td>08/16/2021 - 08/19/2021</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    
  
   <tr>
     <td>11/14/2012</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pre-deformatting](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/sorting#Custom-ascending-/-descending-methods) method to convert the date range data into orderable data as the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['date-range-pre'] = function(date){
  var parts = date.split(" - ");
  return new Date(parts[0]);
};

$('#example_full1').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  order:[[  0, 'desc' ]],
  columnDefs: [
         { 
           targets: 0,
           type: 'date-range'
         }
     ]

} );
  
  
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />

  </head>
  <body>


<table id="example_full1" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th >2</th>
<th  >3</th>
<th>4</th>
</tr>

</thead><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>12/16/2007</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>16</td>
</tr>


  
  <tr>
    <td>09/08/2014 - 09/12/2014</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>08/16/2020</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td>08/16/2021 - 08/19/2021</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>
  
    
  
   <tr>
     <td>11/14/2012</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>test5</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

- by defining `date-range-pre` which format you date range by splitting it then convert first date into `date` type which is sortable type in addition to ignoring second date
- change type of this column to `date-range` inside `columnDefs`

Answer (score 1):

Put an hidden div before your cell content (just one if it's a from-to cell) YYYY-MM-DD format and remove the datable.moment function.

https://live.datatables.net/zasupaza/3/edit

Comment: Thankyou. I am confused. I don't see the table sorting by date correctly.

Comment: You see no changes because i started from your example, that is broken (check the console).
By the way maybe mine is an old solution, you should use data-sort

https://live.datatables.net/dosiliyi/2/edit

Comment: Thankyou, both of the solutions worked. But I picked pre-formatting as I don't have to update the entire table with new sort values. My table has abut 100 rows. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I had the same problem today. For me, it worked to put a `data-sort` attribute with the timestamp on the `td`:

```
<td data-sort="{{ collection.getDateCreated().getTimestamp() }}">
    {{ collection.getCreatedAtString() }}
</td>
```

This will make DataTable to use the value in `data-sort` rather than the value in the tags. Apparently, DataTables calls this [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine DataTables' support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) with some JavaScript to reformat your date string.

In this case, because you have `mm/dd/yyyy` as your format, we will re-arrange the string to be `yyyy/mm/dd` - and then we can rely on the natural sort order of the resulting string.

For your longer date strings `mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy`, we can ignore the second date.

The key point here is: This re-formatting only applies to the data used for sorting. It does not change the data which is displayed to the user, or which is used for searching/filtering.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example_full1').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 0,
      render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
        if (type === 'sort') { // ONLY for data used for sorting
          //console.log(data.substring(6, 10) + '/' + data.substring(0, 5));
          return data.substring(6, 10) + '/' + data.substring(0, 5);
        } else {
          return data; // for display and filtering values
        }
      }
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example_full1" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12/16/2007</td>
          <td>test1</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>09/08/2014 - 09/12/2014</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>08/16/2020</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>08/16/2021 - 08/19/2021</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>11/14/2012</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
          <td>test5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```